# Using icon/image that was imported in a seperate SCSS file

Tags: sass

I need to use a magnifying glass icon in the left of an input field, problem is that all of the icons are imported in a separate SCSS file. How can I use these icons in the search field?

The start of the icons.scss file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "app";
  src:url("../fonts/app.eot");
  src:url("../fonts/app.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("../fonts/app.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("../fonts/app.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../fonts/app.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../fonts/app.svg#app") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: "app" !important;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "app" !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

And the Icon from the file that i want to use:

```
.icon-search:before{
  content: "\43";
}
```

The search SCSS that i want to use the icon in:

```
.search-div{
  padding: 8px 5px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  overflow: hidden;
  .ato-search-bar{
    //Code here for the background icon
  }
}
```

I have imported the icons scss into my other file, but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I assume you're familiar with @import, which would maybe solve your issue

Comment: I am using the @import at the start of my other scss file, however I am not quite sure how to actually use the icon within the 'background: ' element (where there is usually a url).

Comment: Are you importing the icons scss as a css (using url()) or as an scss file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [@extend](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) directive. That means that you will extend your selector with some other selector properties. The extended class will have all the properties of the original class. The `@extend` directive will alsi extends all the defined pseudo selectors.

```
// In your icons.scss file
.icon-search:before{
    content: "\43";
}

// Later in you css (remember to import icons.scss using: @import "icons";
.search-div{
    padding: 8px 5px;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    overflow: hidden;
   .ato-search-bar{
       @extend .icon-search; // Extends the icon class
   }
}
```

Will compile into:

```
.icon-search:before, 
.search-div .ato-search-bar:before {
    content: "\43";
}

.search-div {
    padding: 8px 5px;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope it helps.